# Rspec/Capybara/Poltergeist: How to stub the URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist

For my tests, I would like to stub/fake the URL that the tests are using, so that in Rails my `request.host` shows up as something besides 'www.example.com'

In my research, most people suggest changing capybara's `app_host`, but this only works when you're using the default driver. When using Poltergeist it will actually go to that URL.

Is there anything else I can use?

Comment: When using Capybara/Poltergeist you're doing feature tests that test the full stack.  You should not be attempting to stub/mock anything when doing that (maybe you want a controller spec instead?) .  Additionally when not using the default rack-test driver you should be seeing '127.0.0.1' for request.host in your app (not www.example.com).  You can change the Capybara.app_host to anything you want, but would then to need make sure your local DNS resolved that to 127.0.0.1 (/etc/hosts entry, etc).  Maybe you need to explain a bit more of what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: Yeah, I guess having the DNS resolve it to 127.0.0.1 is what I want (it's what happens in development) but I'm a little worried about what might happen in a CI, like CircleCI. Is there a way to set up a host file using services like that? It might be my best bet.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test that needs that domain name to change?

Comment: My app changes what course it's on by checking the URL. something like 'learn-algebra.com' or 'learn-calculus.com' to know what it should be teaching

Comment: Yes - CircleCI supports setting entries in the hosts file - https://circleci.com/docs/configuration/#hosts

Comment: That'll work then, thanks!! Wish I could mark as answered :)

Comment: Added as an answer you can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Capybara/Poltergeist you're doing feature tests that test the full stack. You should not be attempting to stub/mock anything when doing that (maybe you want a controller spec instead?).

Additionally when not using the default rack-test driver you should be seeing '127.0.0.1' for request.host in your app (not www.example.com). You can change the Capybara.app_host to anything you want, but would then to need make sure your local DNS resolved that to 127.0.0.1 (/etc/hosts entry, etc).  Most CI systems also allow you to specify DNS resolutions - https://circleci.com/docs/configuration/#hosts

Comment: I think there's a limit to this "stub nothing" mentality. E.g. if you're testing payments, you wouldn't want to send real money. I feel that external dependencies (payment processors, AWS etc) can be stubbed. Correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: @MarosHluska Partly correct - In a feature test you'd use a fake for the service that handles payments ( https://github.com/thoughtbot/fake_stripe for example).  You don't want to be doing things that modify your code in feature tests (which mocking/stubbing does) otherwise you're not sure your production code was actually tested.